# How to count all the nodes after parent node in python

Tags: python, tree

[image]

In the given tree when  we pass node-- **2** then output is 5, it counts all the nodes after **2**,
4-5-6-7-8

```
def count(node):
if node is None:
    return 0
return 1+count(node.lchild)+count(node.rchild)
```

but with this, I only count its child nodes

Comment: what do you want output when pass 2?

Comment: child count :  5

Comment: your code is wrong and work only for Binary Tree, this tree is not Binary Tree.

Comment: then how can I count all the nodes?

Comment: Please provide the code with which you define the tree in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, your code is designed for node instances that have `lchild` and `rchild` members, but the tree in the picture has a node with 3 children, so it cannot be represented as such a node.

You need a different definition of your Node class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, *children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children
```

Then I would define `count` as a *method* of that class, not as a stand-alone function:

```
class Node
    # ...

    def count(self):
        return sum(1 + child.count() for child in self.children)
```

Example run:

```
# Create the tree as pictured in the question
root = Node(1,
    Node(2,
        Node(4),
        Node(5,
            Node(7),
            Node(8)
        ),
        Node(6)),
    Node(3)
)

# Select the node with value 2 (at left of root) and call the `count` method:
print(root.children[0].count())
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'left'

Comment: Sorry, last line was of course wrong. Corrected.

Comment: how can i count child node for 5

Comment: Well, you pick the node with value 5, and call `.count()` on it. As the node with 5 is the second child of the node with 2, which is the first child of the root, you can get to it with `root.children[0].children[1]`. Then call like: `root.children[0].children[1].count()`.

Comment: I want to count like this if we pass 2 then output is like - output: **2 have 3 child node, 2 have 2 child of child node**

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs correctly on `Binary Tree` but the `Tree of your question` is not `Binary Tree`, you need a different approach. You need to define `list of child` for every node in your class and use this code:

```
def count(node):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    count = 1
    for child in node_child
        count += count(child)
    return count
```